# Understanding angularJS $resource isArray property

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

i'm learning angular's $resource service and in the [angular tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11) a custom action is added (query) that has its **method** set to 'get' and **isArray** is set to true

```
return $resource('phones/:phoneId.json', {}, {
      query: {method:'GET', params:{phoneId:'phones'}, isArray:true}
 });
```

However, if you look at [the docs for $resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) the 'query' action already has its **method** set to 'get' and **isArray** is already set to true by **default**. So i thought that i can just leave those properties out.

This works for the **method** property, but it turns out that if i leave out the **isArray** property i get this error:

> Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration for action
>   `query`. Expected response to contain an object but got an array

Why is that?

Comment: Did you remove query from $resource? `return $resource('phones/:phoneId.json');`

Comment: no, i just removed the method property and i want to remove the isArray property but that doesn't work

Comment: But why are your creating/replacing a custom query action as there is already one built in? Use the code I posted and the query will work

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood the documentation.

By default without adding any custom actions, the following are supported:

```
'get':    {method:'GET'},
'save':   {method:'POST'},
'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
'delete': {method:'DELETE'}
```

So by default the `query` action expects an array to be returned which makes sense since a query generally would return an array of items.

So if you use:

```
phonecatServices.factory('Phone', ['$resource', function($resource){
    return $resource('phones/phones.json');
}]);
```

You can then perform a query like so:

```
var queryParams = { name: 'test' };

Phone.query(queryParams, {}, function (response) {
    $scope.phones = response;
});
```

Now if you wanted to add a custom action then the default for `isArray` is `false` so:

```
return $resource('phones/:phoneId.json', {}, {
      someCustomAction: {method:'GET', params:{phoneId:'phones'} }
});
```

would need to return an object. If an array was returned then `isArray` would need to be set to `true` like so:

```
return $resource('phones/:phoneId.json', {}, {
      someCustomAction: {method:'GET', params:{phoneId:'phones'}, isArray: true }
});
```

Comment: To be fair, it's REALLY EASY to misunderstand Angular's documentation. :)